# Code structure of website API

Tags: python, web-scraping, api

I manage the Python API for the Manganelo (and Mangakalot) sites and I am not fully convinced that the code structure I currently use is the best. (https://github.com/nixonjoshua98/manganelo)

The API has various objects (MangaInfo, SearchManga, DownloadChapter) and an example of the usage are as follows.

```
from manganelo import SearchManga

search = SearchManga("Naruto")

search.start()

for result in search:
    print(result.title, result.url)
```

~ ~ ~

```
from manganelo import extras

search = extras.SearchMangaThread("Naruto")

search.start()  # Start the search thread

# do stuff here while we search in the background

search.wait()  # Wait for the search to finish if it hasn't already

for r in search:
    print(r)
```

The usage of multiple objects simply feels weird to me, and could be improved upon. The source code of this particular object is below.

```
class SearchManga:
    def __init__(self, query: str) -> None:
        """
        :param query: Query string to search for, we strip the 'illegal' characters ourselves.
        """

        self.query: str = query
        self.results: list = []

    def __str__(self):
        """ Return the query string which was passed in at construction. """
        return self.query

    def __enter__(self):
        """ Context manager entry point. Call .start() before we return the instance. """
        self.start()

        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        """ Context manager exit point """

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        """ Return the length of the internal results list """
        return len(self.results)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        """ Index the internal list """
        return self.results[item]

    def __contains__(self, item):
        """ Check if an item exists in the results """
        return item in self.results

    def __iter__(self):
        """ Used in loops. Simply return results.__iter__ """
        return iter(self.results)

    def start(self):
        """ This is where the magic happens. Sends the request and extracts the information we want. """

        # Generate the URL, which includes removing 'illegal' characters
        url = self._generate_url(self.query)

        # Send the request. Can also raise an exception is the request fails.
        response = utils.send_request(url)

        # Entire page soup
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

        # List of the search results
        results = soup.find_all(class_="search-story-item")

        # Iterate over the results soup and extract the information we want
        for i, ele in enumerate(results):
            manga = utils.find_or_raise(ele, class_="item-img")

            title = manga.get("title", None)  # Manga title
            link = manga.get("href", None)  # Link to the manga 'homepage'

            r = MangaSearchResult(title=title, url=link)

            self.results.append(r)

    def _generate_url(self, query: str) -> str:
        """
        Generate the URL we send the request to, we remove all 'illegal' characters here from the query string.

        :param str query: THe base query string which we are searching for
        :return str: Return the formatted URL
        """
        allowed_characters: str = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + "_"

        query = "".join([char.lower() for char in query.replace(" ", "_") if char in allowed_characters])

        return "http://manganelo.com/search/" + query
```

The object above implements majority of the `list` special methods but forwards them to an internal list since I don't like inheriting from the core types.

**utils**

```
def find_or_raise(soup: BeautifulSoup, *, class_: str) -> Union[bs4.element.Tag, bs4.element.PageElement]:
    """
    Attempts to find a class inside the soup, if the tag cannot be found then raise an exception.

    :param BeautifulSoup soup:  The soup we will try to find the class <class_> in.
    :param str class_:          The class name we are searching for.
    :return:                    We return the element which is a bs4 Tag, but PyCharm marks it as a bs4 PageElement so
                                we use a Union and mark it as both types.
    """
    element = soup.find(class_=class_)

    if element is None:
        raise TagNotFound(f"Tag not found")

    return element


def send_request(url: str, *, timeout: int = 5) -> requests.Response:
    """
    Send a request to the URL provided

    :param str url: The URL which we are sending a GET request to.
    :param timeout: Optional parameter which decides how long we wait before throwing an exception
    :return: The response object
    """
    default_headers = requests.utils.default_headers()

    r = requests.get(url, stream=True, timeout=timeout, headers=default_headers)

    r.raise_for_status()

    return r
```

~ ~ ~

```
class SearchMangaThread(SearchManga):
    def __init__(self, query: str):
        super(SearchMangaThread, self).__init__(query)

        self._thread = threading.Thread(target=super(SearchMangaThread, self).start)

    def start(self):
        self._thread.start()

    def wait(self):
        self._thread.join()

    def done(self):
        return not self._thread.is_alive()

    def __enter__(self):
        self.start()

        return self
```

Looking for any improvements in the overall usage of the API or the code objects. I can add other object examples from the repo if requested.

**Updated**

```
class SearchManga:
    def __init__(self, query: str, *, threaded: bool = False) -> None:
        """
        :param query: Query string to search for, we strip the 'illegal' characters ourselves.
        """
        self.query: str = query

        self._response = None

        if threaded:
            self._thread = threading.Thread(target=self._start)

            self._thread.start()
        else:
            self._start()

    def _start(self):
        # Generate the URL, which includes removing 'illegal' characters
        url = self._generate_url(self.query)

        # Send the request. Can also raise an exception is the request fails.
        self._response = utils.send_request(url)

    def results(self):
        """
        This is where the magic happens. Sends the request and extracts the information we want.
        """
        if hasattr(self, "_thread") and self._thread.is_alive():
            self._thread.join()

        # Entire page soup
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self._response.content, "html.parser")

        # List of the search results
        results = soup.find_all(class_="search-story-item")

        # Iterate over the results soup and extract the information we want
        for i, ele in enumerate(results):
            manga = utils.find_or_raise(ele, class_="item-img")

            title = manga.get("title", None)  # Manga title
            link = manga.get("href", None)  # Link to the manga 'homepage'

            yield MangaSearchResult(title=title, url=link)

    @staticmethod
    def _generate_url(query: str) -> str:
        """
        Generate the URL we send the request to, we remove all 'illegal' characters here from the query string.

        :param str query: THe base query string which we are searching for
        :return str: Return the formatted URL
        """
        allowed_characters: str = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + "_"

        query = "".join([char.lower() for char in query.replace(" ", "_") if char in allowed_characters])

        return "http://manganelo.com/search/" + query
```

Comment: Where is `APIBase` defined?

Comment: @Reinderien I actually removed the base class since posting since it only included two static methods. I have updated the code.

Comment: Please revert your latest edit and move the new code to a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion all of the machinery to make `SearchManga` iterable is needless. Simply change `start` to `yield` its results:

```
    # Iterate over the results soup and extract the information we want
    for i, ele in enumerate(results):
        manga = utils.find_or_raise(ele, class_="item-img")

        title = manga.get("title", None)  # Manga title
        link = manga.get("href", None)  # Link to the manga 'homepage'

        yield MangaSearchResult(title=title, url=link)
```

Anything else is overhead. If you really need this to be multi-threaded (which, given your example that simply `wait`s, you might not), then feed a synchronized `queue.Queue`.

Comment: Thats a fair enough change. Think I will switch over to a generator

Comment: I added the updated version to the question

Comment: CR policy is to make a new question rather than updating the existing one. Please do that.